# "if message/text exists in database", then show the message that the user created from latest to oldest

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on this message system. The user has a form presented to him, where the user will type notes, in this case called a "message". When the user visits his profile page, he is shown the message that he had typed in the form earlier and pressed saved.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEsDg.png

My database has a table called "messages" where I have columns `pid`, `uid`, `message`, `time`, and `picture` where the `uid` is the `uid` in my "users" table.

So the `pid` is a auto-incrementing and the `uid` is the user id of the user who posted the message.
(The user posts a URL to his picture in the form which is later saved to the `picture` column in the database.

My PHP code where I get data from the database:

```
<?php

$uid = $this->session->userdata('uid');

$this->db->limit(10); //Use this to limit the entires while you show the entires on the front page.
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT pid, message, time, picture FROM messages WHERE uid = '$uid';");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)

{
   $message = $row['message'];
   $time = $row['time'];
   $picture = $row['picture'];

}

    ?>
```

My html code in my profile_body.php page in my views folder where I have the above's code included.

```
    <div class="list-group list-group-breakout">
              <a class="list-group-item" href="https://assembly.com/assemblycoins">
                <div class="chip">
  <div class="chip-icon">
    <img alt="Coins" width="48" height="48" class="app-icon" src="<?php echo $picture ?>"/>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

      <p class="omega"><?php echo $message;?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 right-align">

      <p class="gray-2 small omega">
        Feb. 21, 2015 <!-- Not from database -->
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I get only 10 results for the messages that the users typed in the database and display it? I have tried to paste the same html code again but it displays the same message and picture.

Thanks.

Comment: All messages data should be passed to your view. Currently you pass only the last message data.

Comment: What do you mean messages data should be passed to my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some improvements to do :

```
$uid = $this->session->userdata('uid');

$result = $this->db->select('pid, message, time, picture')
         ->where(array('uid' => $uid))
         ->limit(10)
         ->get('messages')
         ->result_array();

$this->load->view('profile_body', $result);
```

In your view `profile_body.php` file :

```
<?php foreach($result as $row): ?>
<div class="list-group list-group-breakout">
              <a class="list-group-item" href="https://assembly.com/assemblycoins">
                <div class="chip">
  <div class="chip-icon">
    <img alt="Coins" width="48" height="48" class="app-icon" src="<?php echo $row['picture'] ?>"/>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

      <p class="omega"><?php echo $row['message'];?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 right-align">

      <p class="gray-2 small omega">
        Feb. 21, 2015 <!-- Not from database -->
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. I'm getting an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in .... on line 22. `On line 22, I have this:   

 ->get('messages')

Comment: Yes, there is a `;` before, i'll remove it `limit(10);` should be just `limit(10)`

Comment: Glad that I could help ^^